# jquery animate rotate div multiple times on click

Tags: jquery, rotation, jquery-animate

I would like to rotate this div on click using animate (not rotate, no plugins), and also set how many times it can rotate. Here is the code

```js
$('#foo').animate({  borderSpacing: -90 }, {
    step: function(now,fx) {
      $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
      $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
      $(this).css('transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
    },
    duration:'slow'
},'linear');
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#foo {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:100px; 
    border-spacing: 0;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">Text</div>
<p>See <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/ERRmd/">inspiration</a>
```

Comment: *how many times it can rotate.* in a single click? or for all clicks??

Comment: For all clicks. I would like to make it to where you can add multiple clicks, and each click has it's own degree please. Thanks.

Comment: The other thing is, I do not want it to reset every time you click on it. Thanks.

Comment: I posted an answer .. please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st**: You need to use `deg` instead of `borderSpacing` to avoid reset every time

**2nd**: I create two functions one for rotate and another one to reset the rotation

**3rd**: add `data` attribute to catch the `angle` and the change on it

The next code/comments will explain those steps: *Please read the comments on code carefully*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#foo').on('click' , function(){ // element click event
    var rotate_deg = parseInt($(this).data('rotate')); // get the data-rotate attribute in this case will return -90 change it on html if you like
    var next_rotation_angle = rotate_deg - 90; //for a new rotation angle .. in this case I use rotate_deg * 2 change it as you like
    var Times = 3; // how many rotate available
    if(rotate_deg / 90 >= -Times){
      RotateIt($(this) , rotate_deg); // run a function to rotate the element 
      $(this).data('rotate' , next_rotation_angle); // append a new angle to data-rotate attribute
    }else{alert('Can not click any more')}
  });
  $('#reset_rotation').on('click' , function(){ // reset button click event
    ResetRotate($('#foo')); // reset the element rotation to 0
    $('#foo').data('rotate' , '-90');
  });
});
//function to rotate .. use this code to rotate any element you need by using RotateIt(element , rotate_deg);
function RotateIt(el , deg){
  $(el).stop().animate({deg: deg}, {
      step: function(now,fx) {
        $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
        $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
        $(this).css('transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
      },
      duration:'slow'
  },'linear');
}
// function to reset the rotate .. while deg here is 0 no need to set deg as an argument 
function ResetRotate(el){
  $(el).stop().animate({deg: 0}, {
      step: function(now,fx) {
        $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
        $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
        $(this).css('transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
      },
      duration:'slow'
  },'linear');
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#foo {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:100px; 
    border-spacing: 0;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo" data-rotate="-90">Text</div>
<p>See <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/ERRmd/">inspiration</a>
<button id="reset_rotation">Reset Rotation</button>
```

Comment: It's really close but then it keeps spinning faster when you keep clicking it for some reason.

Comment: @TylerMaher sure it will because I'm using `rotate_deg * 2` I said read comments .. you can change it to any angle you need .. or even change it to if statement to get a new angle

Comment: @TylerMaher  explain what you want exactly ??

Comment: should be able to rotate at the same speed every time, and have a set limit to how many times it can rotate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution snipet. hope you like it.

```js
$('#act').on('click',function(){
    $(this).animate({  borderSpacing: -90 }, {
        step: function(now,fx) {
            $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
            $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
            $(this).css('transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
        },
        duration:'slow'
    },'linear');
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#act {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:100px; 
    border-spacing: 0;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="act">Text</div>
<p>See <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/ERRmd/">inspiration</a>
```

Hope this will fulfill your requirement.

Greetings!

Comment: It looks great but there's one problem.  I would like to make it to where you can add multiple clicks, and each click has it's own degree please. Thanks.

Comment: The other thing is, I do not want it to reset every time you click on it. Thanks.